# Scrape data HTML table in iframe using R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to scrape the following table from this link:

https://www.price.moc.go.th/en/home_en

Using `rvest` the following doesn't work, but I don't manage to figure out what to change:

Read html code

```
html <- read_html("https://www.price.moc.go.th/en/home_en")
```

Go into specific css selector

```
check <- html %>%
  html_nodes("#cpi_index > td:nth-child(2)") %>%
  html_text()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyC0e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required table is in `iframe` which has a link,

https://www.price.moc.go.th/price_index/index_price01.html

[image]

You need `RSelenium` to get the table.

```
url = 'https://www.price.moc.go.th/price_index/index_price01.html'
#start the browser
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)
#get table
df = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_table() 

df[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  INDEX    `Nov  21` `M/M` `Y/Y` `A/A`
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 CPI           102.  0.28  2.71  1.15
2 CORE-CPI      101.  0.09  0.29  0.23
3 PPI           106.  1.2   8.5   4.4 
4 CMI           116   0.5  10.4   7.9
```

Comment: Dear @Nad Pat, thank you very much! Out of curiosity, how do you spot that a table is of the format iframe ?

Comment: Modified the answer to include picture representing the `iframe` and link which is located beside it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nad Pat!